# How to write unit and integration tests in this scenario?

Tags: unit-testing

I have algorithm which needs data from data sources like mysql,  cassandra,  hdfs  now algorithm process data and stores in same locations.logic has input dao ,business logic and output dao. I have written unit test by mocking input and output dao but total code coverage is less because dao and services are not covered  how to make sure such classes are covered in test cases ?
How to write unit tests for dao classes?
Through integration tests by calling real data base ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to write unit tests for dao classes?

You usually don't.

> Through integration tests by calling real database?

That's the correct approach. It makes little to no sense having unit tests for DAO classes as in order to write them you would have to mock out database... which would lead to testing what exactly? You would test nothing (or mocks at best).

Comment: I also do not see any sense in writing unit tests to DAO classes which are just inserting or updating in table . But if it is using say some DB logic like stored procedure or some DB lock then it makes sense to test it .